# add serializer method field to a generics.ListAPIView - Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model , its name is Permit.
my OS windows 7
django 3.2
serializer class:

```
class PermitListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self,page=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page = page
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    page_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    userfullname = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    show_subsystem = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  
    def get_show_subsystem(self,obj):
        return obj.subsystem.name
    def get_userfullname(self, obj):
        return obj.issuer.get_full_name() if obj.issuer.get_full_name() else 'Unknown'
    def get_page_number(self, obj):
        return self.page
    class Meta:
        model = Permit
        fields = '__all__'
```

my view:

```
class c_receive_tm(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PermitListSerializer 
    filter_backends=(filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields=('name', 'description')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Permit.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

by I get an error:

```
TypeError at /api/receive_tm/
Object of type Permit is not JSON serializable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/receive_tm/
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Object of type Permit is not JSON serializable
```

if i remove all SerializerMethodField its works
I need this additional fields

Comment: Provide also your models.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with self.page, can you tell why did you use the init in your serializer ?
BTW you can use serializer.ReadOnlyField(source='subsystem.name') instead of your method fields

Comment: I want to implement pagination myself i removed self.page now its works :)